# How do i print String of Array Using For...in Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
let arr = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Watermelon']

for (let x in arr) {
  console.log(x);
}
```

I want to print String elements from the given array whenever I try to access using the above code it only prints index positions so kindly help me with the proper solution

Answer (score 0):

not **in** rather **of**

**wrong**: `element in arr`

```js
const arr = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Watermelon'];

for (const x in arr) {
  console.log(x);
}

// 0-1-2
```

**right**: `element of arr`

```js
const arr = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Watermelon'];

for (const x of arr) {
  console.log(x);
}

// Apple, Banana, Watermelon
```